# Windows 8 javascript application

Tags: microsoft-metro, controls

This is with respect to development of Windows 8 javascript applications -

The controls should be positioned correctly irrespective of the various screen resolutions that Windows 8 metro application supports.
Is there any property that can be commonly set for the controls?

Answer (score 0):

This is called responsive design. Normally to position html elements you use css.  You would use percentages and appropriate positioning so that your controls look good everywhere.

However, you can take it a step further and set "media queries" to position your elements efficiently when there are different screen resolutions.  Examples here: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

So based on screen size, you can make drastic positioning changes to controls.  For example, you can have a horizontally displayed orientation go vertical when in portrait mode.

Media queries apply to not just resolution, but also to contrast mode and other parameters.

For a list of media queries in Windows 8, you can see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453556.aspx